# SQL Server Query Ordering Help Required

Tags: t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a table EMPLOYEE defined as below:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
  Employee varchar(50),
  Manager varchar(50),
  field1 bit,
  field2 bit 
) 
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('Emp1','Mgr1',1,0)
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('Contactor1','',0,0)
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('Mgr1','',0,1)
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('Mgr2','',0,1)
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('Emp2','Mgr2',1,0)
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('Emp3','Mgr2',1,0)
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('Contractor2','',0,0)
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('Emp4','Mgr1',1,0)
```

Assumptions:

1. if field1 is equal to 1 then, the entity is employee.
2. If field2 is equal to 1 then, the entity is manager.
3. If field1 and field2 is equal to 0 then, the entity is contractor.
4. A particular row cannot have value 1 for both field1 and field2.

The query SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE returns following values:

[image]

I need a query so that I can get the result in the following format:

[image: Desired Output]

basically, the result should have the first manager followed by corresponding employees then, the next manager followed by corresponding employees and finally there should be all the Contractors.

Comment: It would (generally) help if you introduced a column that distinguished the type of employees, rather than having to depend on the names - e.g. managers and contractors are indistinguishable except by name, from your data.

Comment: Also, do you need this to extend to more levels. E.g. could a row with values (`Emp99,Emp1`) exist, and should it appear between rows 2&3 of your expected result?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Have added the fields. for 2nd question, (Emp99,Emp1) is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just based on your sample data and expected results, this works:

```
select * from Employee order by
CASE WHEN Employee like 'C%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, --Force Contractors to the end
COALESCE(NULLIF(Manager,''),Employee), --Get employees and their managers together
CASE WHEN Employee like 'M%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, --Sort Managers before employees
Employee --Sort by employee name
```

But note my questions in my comments if you have more complex data

With `field1` and `field2` as defined in amended question:

```
select * from Employee order by
CASE WHEN field1=0 and field2=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, --Force Contractors to the end
COALESCE(NULLIF(Manager,''),Employee), --Get employees and their managers together
field2 desc, --Sort Managers before employees
Employee --Sort by employee name
```

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliver  The 1 or 0 in the Order BY clause refers to column ids or the ascending and descending order? Also, Can you answer the question using field1 and field2.

Comment: @Abhineet - the 1s and 0s were just numeric values that had the desired properties

Comment: In my database I do not have the Manager and Employee column names. I have to work only with field 1 and field 2. So, If I modify query to 
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN field1=0 and field2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
COALESCE(field2,field1),
field2 desc,
field1

I am not getting the desired output :(

Answer (score 1):

The basic ordering would be

```
... ORDER BY Manager + Employee
```

If Manager allowed NULL, which is better IMO

```
... ORDER BY ISNULL(Manager, Employee)
```

For for SQL Server 2012, whether NULL or not

```
... ORDER BY CONCAT(Manager,Employee)
```

However, there is no discriminator to show Employee vs Contractor vs Manager differences

So using the actual string values...

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Employee LIKE 'Contractor%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    CONCAT(Manager,Employee)
```